# Custom layout and filter for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I have created my own adapter which extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable.

**1.** I am occasionally getting index out of bounds error, in getView method:

```
    private ArrayList<ResultHolderData> originalData;
    private ArrayList<ResultHolderData> arrayList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<ResultHolderData> suggestions;


   public static class ResultHolderData {
     public String symbol;
     public String fullName;
     public ResultHolderData(String a, String b) {
            symbol=a;
            fullName=b;
     }
   }

public static class ResultHolder {
      public TextView symName;
      public TextView symNameFull;
 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ResultHolder rh;

if(convertView==null) {
    rh=new ResultHolder();
    convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_line_dropdown_item, null);
    rh.symName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autocompleteSym);
    rh.symNameFull=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autocompleteName);
    convertView.setTag(rh);
} else {
    rh=(ResultHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

//rh.symName.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

 /***THE BELLOW LINE THROWS THE ERROR***/
rh.symName.setText(arrayList.get(position).symbol);
rh.symNameFull.setText(arrayList.get(position).fullName);
//rh.symName.setText(arrayList.get(position));

return convertView;
}
```

The arrayList represents the filtered resultSet:

```
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
   if(results.count>0 && results!=null) {
       arrayList=(ArrayList<ResultHolderData>) results.values;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   } else {
       notifyDataSetInvalidated();
   }

}
```

The error occurs sometimes, when you have 2 items in dropdown suggestions and when typing another letter causes the dropdown to only suggest one item. Then it says: Invalid index 1, size is 1. Or size is 0..

---

My opinion: It usually happens when i am typing in fast, so i assume that NotifyDataSetChanged is in progress, but the publishResults changes the content of the arrayList and this causes the error. But then again i would expect this to happen in more situations?

**2.** Also another error pops out: **The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.**

*And the only place where i change the contents of adapter is in publishResults? Why is this happening then?*

Its obvious i got something wrong here, or i dont completely understand how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i posted the same question twice when i despair, here is the answer i gave: [Errors with custom BaseAdapter for AutoCompleteTextView(indexOutOfBounds & content changed but no notification)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920459/errors-with-custom-baseadapter-for-autocompletetextviewindexoutofbounds-conte/18933841#18933841)

The problem was this line in publishResults:

```
arrayList=(ArrayList<ResultHolderData>) results.values;
```

which just pointed arrayList to those results, instead i made a "shallow copy" and cleared the list before it:

```
  arrayList.clear();
  for(ResultHolderData tempRhd : (ArrayList<ResultHolderData>)results.values)
           arrayList.add(tempRhd);
```

and problem solved!